# Get Select Column names from dynamic query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

If I have a random query, and would like to return the column names from this query:

```
SELECT 1 ONE, 2 TWO, 'THREE' THREE
```

How can I return the column names? Maybe even the column data type as well.

I can do this in c#, but I am looking for a way to do this all purely inside of Ms Sql.

Is this possible, if so how?

Would I have to create a temporary table, then check the info schema table? Or can I do it another way?

Comment: im interested on how to do this in old sql versions

Comment: @Katana I added an extra line to my answer that might help.

Comment: @DavidG thanks additional knowledge for me, i'd added FMTONLY before when i encountered issue on communication between entity framework and my SP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx) to describe the columns returned from an arbitrary SQL statement. For example:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql = 'SELECT 1 ONE, 2 TWO, ''THREE'' THREE'
```

You will get results like this [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/6804).

For older versions of SQL Server, you can also look at [`SET FMTONLY ON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx).