# TSQL get column names from dynamic query with formatting/conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to identify list of columns and its original value from dynamic SQL.

Example: I have this SQL statement:

```
@tsql = N'SELECT A.ID AS PROCESSID, COALESCE(STEP_ID,'''') AS programmid, NAME FROM DBO.TBL_LOG A'
```

As per [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255470/get-select-column-names-from-dynamic-query-in-sql-server) It will just return column name. I need both column name and its original value.

Expected result :

[image]

Can anyone please help with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is heavy string parsing... You might split your statement between `SELECT` and `FROM` at commas, but that's not enough... There's a comma in your `COALESCE()` too. This would need to count opening and closing paranthesis... Furthermore T-SQL allows a lot of freedom: whitespace, linebreaks, quotes, the `AS` is not mandatory... T-SQL is not the rigth tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me temporary  , If there will be too complex statement in select clause than it will not work.

```
;WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT NAME , SUBSTRING(LTRIM(@TSQL),7,CHARINDEX('FROM',LTRIM(@TSQL),0)-7) as QRY FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set  (@TSQL, null, 0) 
    )
    ,COLPOS as
    (
    select NAME,QRY, CHARINDEX(NAME ,QRY,LEN(QRY) - CHARINDEX(REVERSE(NAME),REVERSE(QRY),0)- LEN(NAME)) AS POS
    FROM CTE
    )
    ,POS AS (
    SELECT NAME,QRY,POS,LAG(POS) OVER (order by (select 1)) LGPOS,LEAD(POS) OVER (order by (select 1)) LEADPOS  
    ,LAG(NAME) OVER (order by (select 1)) LGNAME
    FROM COLPOS
    )
    SELECT NAME , LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING (QRY,COALESCE(LGPOS+LEN(LGNAME),0),POS+LEN(NAME)-COALESCE(LGPOS+LEN(LGNAME),0)))) AS EXPRESSION
    FROM POS
```